# Looking for a query to differentiate record based on month/year

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

I have the following table:

| month | year | first_seen | last_seen | ent1 | ent2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-02 | 223035722222 | 44414152023333 |
| 2 | 2020 | 2020-03-02 | 2021-03-02 | 223035744444 | 44414152022009 |
| 1 | 2021 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 | 223035744444 | 44414152022009 |
| 1 | 2021 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 | 223035743333 | 44414152021008 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-02 | 223035743333 | 44414152021008 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-08 | 542232323323 | 55524334455433 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-09 | 343223344555 | 44343434343444 |

Now i want to skip those entries which have same **first_seen** and **last_seen** and have only one entry, that is if an entry have same **first_seen** and **last_seen** but is in two different months or years than that entry will not be skipped.

For example from the above table, i want the following result:

| month | year | first_seen | last_seen | ent1 | ent2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020 | 2020-03-02 | 2021-03-02 | 223035744444 | 44414152022009 |
| 1 | 2021 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 | 223035744444 | 44414152022009 |
| 1 | 2021 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 | 223035743333 | 44414152021008 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-02 | 223035743333 | 44414152021008 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-08 | 542232323323 | 55524334455433 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-09 | 343223344555 | 44343434343444 |

In the resulting table above only the first row is skipped because it has same **first_seen** and **last_seen** and is appeared only once. Though the **row 2** & **row 3** of the **table 1** have same condition but appeared more than once (different year) and **row 4** & **row 5** have the same condition as well but appeared in different months.

Comment: The table have millions of entries and is partitioned on month and year

Comment: row 4 & row 5 do not satisfy first_seen = last_seen then why is it in the expected result?

Comment: The first_seen != last_seen for those two rows so they should appear, only those rows **should not** appear which have the condition **first_seen = last_seen**.

Comment: Only the first row from **table 1** is skipped because it has first_seen = last_seen and have only one entry i.e is not appeared in any other month or year

Comment: We are also looking at **ent1** and **ent2** column for filtration of results, but that comes later.

Comment: @Popeye any hint will workout for me.

Comment: is it the condition first_seen = last_seen and first_seen or last_seen doesn't appear in any other rows? Only then i think 5th row satisfy the condition.

Comment: Or are you considering ent1 wise single entry for exclusion where first_seen=last_seen?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur if the first_seen = last_seen than that row does not appear (only if there if the same entry only appear once, i.e it is not in any other month or year with first_seen=last_seen)

Comment: yes ent1 wise single entry exclusion where first_seen = last_seen, (only single entry, single entry means same ent1 & ent2 value)

Comment: but if the same entry (ent1 &ent2) appears with any other month or year than it is not excluded.

Comment: We can consider a procedure/function, with IF/ELSE :)

Answer (score 1):

First I have identified row counts for ent1 and ent2 then I have selected only those rows having count>1 or first_seen<>last_seen. Please check it out:

```
with Results as (
select * ,count(*) over(partition by ent1,ent2  rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) Row_Count
from S66096277 
)
select  month,year,first_seen,last_seen,ent1,ent2 
from results 
where Row_Count>=2 or first_seen<>last_seen;
```